# Passing value from parent form to .NET control via javascript. Gridview Selectparameter from window.opener

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, parameters, parent-child

I have two asp.net forms.

The first form opens a popup window to the second using onclick javascript as follows:

```
onclientclick="javascript:PS=window.open('https://site/PS.aspx','PS','width=800,height=600,scrollbars=1');PS.focus()"
```

the second form has a .net gridview with a SelectParameter.

```
 <SelectParameters>
 <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="???" Name="FirstName" DefaultValue="="  PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
 </SelectParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

How can I set the value of the parameter to the value of control on the parent form? I don't want to use a session variable or a querystring if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pull a value from the parent window like this:

On the parent form, add a hidden field and create a function like this to access it's value:

```
getParameterValue = function(){
    return document.getElementById("<%=HiddenCtrl.UniqueID%>").value;    
}
```

Add a hidden field in the child window too, and set the value like this:

```
document.getElementById("<%=ChildHiddenCtrl.UniqueID%>").value = window.opener.getParameterValue();
```

And then for your control parameter, use ChildHiddenCtrl:

```
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ChildHiddenCtrl" ... >
```

Comment: In retrospect, I'm okay with passing the value in querystring. But my problem is the onclick event in inline on the control and I need a client function to find the control's value, I have that function, but can't seem to format in such a way that the XSLT will take it.  By chance do you have a sample of where embedding the value of a control in url on the onclick line?

Comment: Can you edit your answer to give more persective on the problem you're having?

Comment: Sorry, you answer is valid for my orgiinal question. my bad. I'm just trying to parameterize an onlick with a value in a textbox.  Would be easy except it's wrapped in XSLT and I can't use < because it breaks formating.  I'd like to do this <xsl:value-of select='@sometextbox'/>' where the query key would go. but get the character < cannot be used.

Comment: I think you have a small syntax error with the way you're calling that XSL argument. Try this: <xsl:value-of select="$sometextbox" />